# Активное меню SrollSpy

Tags: jquery, menu

Есть код , идея в том чтобы активному пункту меню присваивался класс, сейчас класс присваивается для a href="", а нужно чтобы класс добавлялся для li, не понимаю как правильно описать, то что сейчас
`$('li').children('a[href="#' + id+ '"]').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );` - такой вариант добавляет, но не удаляет класс у ссылок

```js
$(function(){


 $("nav").on('click', '[href*="#"]', function(e){
   var offset = 0;
   $('html,body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top - offset }, 1000);
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});

$(window).bind('scroll', function() {
    var currentTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var elems = $('.block');
    elems.each(function(index){
      var elemTop  = $(this).offset().top;
      var elemBottom  = elemTop + $(this).height();
      if(currentTop >= elemTop && currentTop <= elemBottom){
        var id   = $(this).attr('id');
        var navElem = $('a[href="#' + id+ '"]');
    navElem.parent().addClass('active').siblings().removeClass( 'active' );
 
      }
    })
});
```

```css
nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 20px;
  z-index: 9999; }
  nav ul {
    list-style: none; }
    nav ul li {
      display: inline-block; }
      nav ul li a {
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: #666;
        color: #fff; }
        nav ul li a:hover {
          background-color: #999999;
          color: #fff;
          text-decoration: none; }
        nav ul li a:active {
          background-color: #333333; }

.active {
  background-color: skyblue; }
  .active:hover, .active:active {
    background-color: #5bbce4 !important; }


.block {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh; }

.block-1 {
  background: tomato; }

.block-1 {
  background: #ff8c66; }

.block-2 {
  background: #ffb366; }

.block-3 {
  background: #ffd966; }

.block-4 {
  background: #ffff66; }

.block-5 {
  background: #d9ff66; }
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<nav>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
              <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
              <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
              <li><a href="#four">Four</a></li>
              <li><a href="#five">Five</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
 
 <div class="block block-1" id="one"></div>
  <div class="block block-2" id="two"></div>
   <div class="block block-3" id="three"></div>
    <div class="block block-4" id="four"></div>
     <div class="block block-5" id="five"></div>
```

Comment: Класс добавляется и удаляется для li. Какой тогда вопрос?

Comment: верно, мне нужно переопределить куда должен добавляться класс active, цель чтобы active появлялся у <a href="#" class="active"> а не у li

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9j5nnuoo/

Comment: это ваш вариант https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9j5nnuoo/1/ - меняем немного css и он также работает

Comment: да, я думал об этом, но задал сам себе вопрос как бы это через jquery сделать чтобы именно для <a> добавлялся класс =)